# inserting and deleting rows in the most optimal way

Tags: mysql

i have an existing table

```
id, name, user
15, bob, 1
25, alice, 2
30, ann, 1
55, bob, 2
66, candy, 1
```

we want the name records for user 1 to now be set to the values in this string:

```
"ann, candy, dave"
```

if I do it the easy way

```
delete from table where user = 1
insert into table (name,user) values (ann,1), (candy,1), (dave,1)`
```

then the table now looks like this

```
id, name, user
25, alice, 2
55, bob, 2
67, ann, 1
68, candy, 1
69, dave, 1
```

i.e. new rows are created. I don't want the new identities, and over time in huge tables, this causes fragmentation and identity holes and so on. what is the most efficient way in SQL to reduce this to just the actual 2 required operations:

delete from table where user = 1 and name is not in the string "ann, candy, dave", so that the table is then:

```
25, alice, 2
30, ann, 1
```

55, bob, 2
66, candy, 1
`

insert into table user = 1, name = any value from "ann, candy, dave" that does not match name/user=1 , so that the table is then:

`25, alice, 2
30, ann, 1
55, bob, 2
66, candy, 1
67, dave, 1`

Comment: identity holes? there's no such thing. The numbers do not know that they're fragmented.

Comment: @Strawberry: in past cases (admittedly mostly with MS SQL instead) I've hit boundaries because auto_increment id reached its maximum value or hit the INTEGER boundary because of massive amounts of delete-and-recreate over time (someone had decided a 32-bit int was "big enough", pfft!). I've also seen data size blowouts because of "empty" data rows and the way db storage works, particularly with indexes. shrinking any db is a PITA. Also annoying if the identity happens to be referenced without integrity.

Comment: But the solution you propose is the opposite of integrity! It's so bad, it doesn't even have a name.

Comment: @Strawberry: references without integrity are a thing that happens. I don't like it, but its how things get jimmied together and over time they get fixed. Watching the growth of the database is critical, not touching rows can stop indexes in partitions from being rebuilt or physically change on disk. what is your better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a list and want to process it twice, once for deletes and once for inserts.  Store the list in a temporary table and use that for processing.

Along the way, start with a unique index on `user, name` to prevent updates into the table:

```
create unique index idx_table_user_name on table(user, name);
```

This seems to be a requirement for your data, so let the database enforce it.  Then the code for processing is like:

```
create temporary table toprocess as (
     select 1 as user, 'ann' as name union all
     select 1, 'candy' union all
     select 1, 'dave'
    );

create index idx_toprocess_user_name on toprocess(user, name);

delete t
    from table t
    where t.user in (select p.user from toprocess p) and
          not exists (select 1 from toprocess p where p.user = t.user and p.name = t.name);

insert into table(user, name)
    select user, name
    from toprocess
    on duplicate key update user = values(user);
```

Although this might look a bit complicated, it lets you handle multiple users at the same time.  And, the list for processing is only entered once, which reduces the scope for error.

Comment: Hmm, yes this looks better than anything I'd come up with. Letting the DB do the work is the name of the game, so the unique index on the temp table is a great idea! Processing my incoming string to build the temp table becomes the thing (when the string has dozens of entries).

Answer (score 0):

It is not so clear but may be this is what you want:

```
delete from table where user = 1 and name not in('ann', 'candy', 'dave')

insert into table
select * from(select 'ann' as name
              union all
              select 'candy'
              union all
              select 'dave') t
where t.name not in(select name from table where user = 1)
```